# Tensorflow: num_intra_threads and num_inter_threads

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I'm trying to clarify two parameters: `intra_op_parallelism_threads`  and `inter_op_parallelism_threads` . I assume `intra_op_parallelism_threads`  means the number of threads tensorflow can use to parallel a single ops and `inter_op_parallelism_threads`  means the number of threads tensorflow can use to parallel multiple ops when those ops can be run concurrently. If so, I have two questions:

1. Why does each tensorflow process create two seperate threadpools? According [to the doc for tf.configproto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/26b4dfa65d360f2793ad75083c797d57f8661b93/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L165), two seperate thread pools are created based on two parameters, but I assume only the inter_op_parallelism_thread pool is containing the threads that can run the ops, right?
2. Why does Intel use the following configuration?

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [intel.com](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/55/5d/tensorflow-optimizations-img-02.png))</sub>

If inter-op consists with `inter_op_parallelism_threads`, does it mean tensorflow can have 44 threads for a single op but 1/2 for multiple ops?

Could someone please help me clarify these concepts? Thanks!